# Fastest way to determine sequence from stream in c#

Tags: c#, performance, stream, compare, readline

I need to read bytes (converted from string to byte array and then sent to stream) from stream and stop reading as soon as I encounter specific sequence, in my case it's [13, 10, 13, 10] or "\r\n\r\n" if converted to string (ASCII).

Currently I have two versions of the same process:
1) Read from stream one byte at time and check EVERY byte if last 4 bytes of read sequence equals [13, 10, 13, 10] **(note that I can't read and check every 4 bytes as sequence can be 7 bytes long, for example, so it'll read first 4 bytes and then stuck because only 3 of 4 bytes are available)**:

```
NetworkStream streamBrowser = tcpclientBrowser.GetStream();
byte[] data;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    byte[] check = new byte[4] { 13, 10, 13, 10 };
    byte[] buff = new byte[1];
    do
    {
        streamBrowser.Read(buff, 0, 1);
        ms.Write(buff, 0, 1);
        data = ms.ToArray();
    } while (!data.Skip(data.Length - 4).SequenceEqual(check));
}
```

2) Use *StreamReader.ReadLine* to read until "\r\n" and then read again to see if returned line is *null*, and then add to first returned string "\r\n", that way I'll get string that ends with "\r\n\r\n".

My question is - **what method is preferable in terms of perfomance** (if any, it may be that both are too slow and there are better way which I really would want to know)?

Comment: Do you must use byte array converted from string? I mean, can't you manipulate the first received string before to do convertions?

Comment: What are you planning on doing with the left over 3 bytes? Also, its a bad idea to try to pre-optimize your code, you may be pleasantly surprised what you write is fast enough :)

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "stop reading", because StreamReader.ReadLine might very well consume more bytes from underlying stream than just until newline.

Comment: I know you are terminating your messages with end of line characters but a really performant way many wire protocols use is something called Message Framing. Tell the server or client how big the message is and stop when the byte count reaches it.

Comment: @RogersonNazário Well, as far as I understand, you are forced to use byte[] for stream read and write so I have no choise other than convert string to byte[], send to stream, read byte[] from stream and convert it to string.

Comment: @SamMarion regarding leftover 3 bytes - I just described a problem where array like [1, 5, 20, 13, 10, 13, 10] can't be read properly using Read(buff, 0, 4) because StreamReader will be stuck when he will try to read part that left in the end ([10, 13, 10]). On the other hand, reading one byte at time will solve this problem. Regarding speed - I'd be happy if it's fast enough, I am just not sure, reading one byte at time looks horrible to me in terms of perfomance.

Comment: @SamMarion Regarding Message Framing - sadly it's a big No to me because I read from stream that I do not control - I just know that last 4 bytes will be [13,10,13,10] (I am reading HTTP packets from browser and websites).

Comment: `what method is preferable in terms of perfomance` https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @Evk Isn't ReadLine reads data from stream strictly until it encounter "\r", "\n" or "\r\n"? I'd honestly prefer first method (read one byte at time) or any other method, I just don't know if it's good in terms of perfomance or not.

Comment: @mjwills I actually will do that soon, I just wanted to know if there are far better ways than my both methods or if one of my methods significantly worse than other and it's common knowledge to most.

Comment: It uses a buffer of given size (by default 1024 bytes as I rememeber). So it will always consume at least that number of bytes from underlying stream (unless end of stream is sooner of course). That doesn't necessary mean that it's a problem, that's why I ask. Usually it's fine.

Comment: I would be surprised if reading one byte at a time is going to be your bottle neck. I would go that route. If that's too slow I would try something from there but if you don't have a message length I think that's your best bet.

Comment: @Evk I actually didn't know that. If that's a case then this method is pretty bad for me, then it would be better to just read 1024 bytes myself and search for \r\n\r\n.

Comment: But that is exactly what it does, so why do it yourself? Why is it a problem to read more from socket? You usually will read the rest later anyway.

Comment: @SamMarion Well, reading byte by byte may be fast, but I am more concerned about converting whole MemoryStream to array, using .Skip() and then SequenceEqual every single byte. It looks like it'll take alot of time to process files that are couple of MBytes of size.

Comment: @Evk problem is that I read HTTP packets from browser so I need to get exactly one Request from stream, not more and not less and then send it to website. Then do exact same thing for website - precisely read one Response and send it to browser and then repeat. Another problem is that Browser maybe can send some data after first packet, but maybe not and I can't wait after I get first request.

Answer (score -1):

I am drunk, but maybe it will help:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream (new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });

            var sequence = new byte[] { 6, 7, 8 };

            var buffer = new byte[1];
            var queue = new Queue<byte> ();
            int position = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                int count = ms.Read (buffer, 0, 1);

                if (count == 0) return;

                queue.Enqueue (buffer[0]);
                position++;

                if (IsSequenceFound (queue, sequence))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Found sequence at position: " + (position - queue.Count));
                    return;
                }

                if (queue.Count == sequence.Length) queue.Dequeue ();
            }
        }

        static bool IsSequenceFound (Queue<byte> queue, byte[] sequence)
        {
            return queue.SequenceEqual (sequence);
            // normal for (int i ...) can be faster
        }
    }
}
```